# Constructor question (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, class, constructor

At my "Portfolio" constructor it thinks my debugger thinks that I am trying to have a return type set to it. I dont understand why.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class BankAccount
{
private:
int accountNum;
double accountBal;
double annualIntRate;
public:
BankAccount(int, double balance = 0.0, double rate = 0.0);
BankAccount();
void enterAccountData();
void computeInterest(int);
void displayAccount();
double getBalance();
};
 //implementation section:
BankAccount::BankAccount()
{
accountNum = 0;
accountBal = 0;
annualIntRate = 0;
}
BankAccount::BankAccount(int account, double balance, double rate)
{
const int LOWEST = 1000;
const int HIGHEST = 9999;

if(account < LOWEST || account > HIGHEST)
{
    accountNum = 0;
}

else
{
    accountNum = account;
}

accountBal = balance;
annualIntRate = rate;
}
void BankAccount::enterAccountData()
{
cout << setprecision(2) << fixed;   

cout << "Enter the account number " << endl;
cin >> accountNum;

while(accountNum < 1000)
{
    cout << "Account numbers cannot be negative or less than 1000 " <<
        "Enter a new account number: " << endl;
    cin >> accountNum;
}

cout << "Enter the account balance " << endl;
cin >> accountBal;

while(accountBal < 0)
{
    cout << "Account balances cannot be negative. " <<
        "Enter a new account balance: " << endl;
    cin >> accountBal;
}
}
void BankAccount::computeInterest(int months)
{
const int MONTHS_IN_YEAR = 12;
int years = 0;
double rate = 0; 
int count = 0;

cout << endl << "How many years will account # " << accountNum << " be held for? (1 to 40 years) " << endl;
cin >> years;
months = years * 12;
count = 0;
while(years < 1 || years > 40)
{
    cout << "Term must be from 1 to 40." << endl;
    cin >> years;
}
do
{
 accountBal = accountBal * annualIntRate + accountBal;
 count++;
 if(count == 12)
 {
    cout << endl << "The balance after " << months << " months is " << endl;
 }
}while(count < months);

cout << "$" << accountBal << endl;
}
void BankAccount::displayAccount()
{
    cout << "Account: " << accountNum << endl << "Balance is: " <<
    accountBal << endl << "Interest rate is: " << annualIntRate;
    cout << endl;
}
double BankAccount::getBalance()
{
return accountBal;
}
class Portfolio
{
private:
int clientNum;
BankAccount checkingAccount;
BankAccount savingsAccount;
double stockMarketHld;
double estateHld;
public:
Portfolio(int,int,double,int,double,double,double,double);
void balancePortfolio();
}
Portfolio::Portfolio(int client, int checkNum, double checkBal,
int savingNum, double savingBal, double savingRate, double stock, double estate)
 : checkingAccount(checkNum, checkBal), 
savingsAccount(savingNum, savingBal, savingRate)
{
clientNum = client;
stockMarketHld = stock;
estateHld = estate;
balancePortfolio();
}
void Portfolio::balancePortfolio()
{
cout << "This works, yay ^_^" << endl;
}
int main()
{
BankAccount bankAcct1(3452);
BankAccount bankAcct2(4325, 0, 0.53);
BankAccount bankAcct3(1113, 58392, 0.25);
BankAccount bankAcct4(4444, 86);
bankAcct1.displayAccount();
bankAcct2.displayAccount();
bankAcct3.displayAccount();
bankAcct4.displayAccount();

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

It Happens here, if I take out "double stock and double estate" it works....

```
 Portfolio::Portfolio(int client, int checkNum, double checkBal,
int savingNum, double savingBal, double savingRate, double stock, double estate)
 : checkingAccount(checkNum, checkBal), 
savingsAccount(savingNum, savingBal, savingRate)
{
```

Can anyone shed some light on things for me?

Comment: You are missing a semi-colon at the end of your Portfolio class definition. Could be confusing your compiler.

Comment: there is no such construct like while do. You confusing this with do while;

Comment: @Thereis: Oh there is a while loop then after there is a "Do while" loop.

Comment: fair enough, my mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing the semicolon at the end of `class Portfolio { ... };`.  The compiler then proceeds to get confused on the next thing in the file.

Comment: Ugh... thanks I forget that classes need semi colons all the time and wasn't seeing my mistake this time....thank you. Any other pointers you could give me? Just in case my code doesn't look all that great? I am going to try and implement #ifndef and #endif at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks fine except that you forgot to put the semicolor `;` at the end of `Portfolio` class definition:

```
class Portfolio
{
  private:
    int clientNum;
    BankAccount checkingAccount;
    BankAccount savingsAccount;
    double stockMarketHld;
    double estateHld;
  public:
    Portfolio(int,int,double,int,double,double,double,double);
    void balancePortfolio();
}; //<------------ you forgot this!
```

Comment: Yeah dumb mistake on my part : / Why can't they just say "at line such and such" you forgot a semicolon -.-;